# C# -- Eval function, without DataTable?

Tags: c#

I want to create an Eval() function in C# without using DataTables. This is for my CS A-level course. We've been tasked with creating a calculator, but I want to use and Eval instead of "input a + b" &c.

My idea is that it would acquire the user input and check for the first 'function', and solves that. For instance,

The user inputs ("2 + 3 + 4 + 5").

The program would then see "2 + 3" and solve that. ("=5")

The program would then store this integer in a temporary variable, and then go 
on to do the next calculation. "5 + 4" ("=9")

Do you see where I'm going?

My idea was that in actually doing the calculation, it would first acquire the first number; in this instance, 2; and then find the end number; in this instance, 3; and then find the operand; in this instance, +. It would then go on to perform 2 + 3.

I'm relatively new to C#, so this is proving to be quite a challenge. Is anyone willing to help me?

Thanks.

Comment: C# is not a scripting language and was not designed to evaluate arbitrary expressions.

Comment: Also, using `Eval` is *cheating* :) This exercise is meant to teach you how to implement an expression evaluator by yourself.

Comment: Well the whole exercise is to make a calculator. I've stated that I want to make an eval function myself. I've even excluded DataTables, which makes life a whole lot easier.